# JMeter - submit JMeter function inside a script (JSR223 element)

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Functions are very useful for writing a functional script and also helpful without writing real code.

Currently I can execute functions in most of Test Plan except in Script of JSR223 Sampler for example.

Is there a way to enable JMeter function inside JSR223/Beanshell script?
For example ${__log(Message)} or ${__Random(0,10)}

If the call for variable as ${..} is an issue, is there a workaround for calling a function?

Maybe there will be a problem calling groovy function inside groovy script, But can other functions be executed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **should not be inlining [JMeter functions and/or Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) into scripts** as :

- They might resolve into something causing compilation failure or unexpected behavior
- In case of Groovy they will conflict with [GStringTemplate](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/text/GStringTemplateEngine.html), moreover [compiled scripts caching](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/compile-groovyscript-at-runtime-allow-caching-of-compiled-source-to-avoid-recompilation-at-runtime-using-groovyclassloader/) will not be possible

So you have 2 options:

1. Use "Parameters" section of the [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) like:

   [image: JMeter Groovy Functions]
2. Go for code-based equivalents, i.e. using [RandomUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomUtils.html) class:

   [image: JMeter Groovy Random NUmber]

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)