# Generate random values in JSR223 sampler in JMeter

Tags: random, groovy, jmeter, jsr223

```js
def index = [];
def randoms = [];
def size = new File("C:/Users/320027671/Desktop/JmeterPerformanceSuit/CompleteSuit/STU3/Post/index.csv").readLines().size();
File file = new File("C:/Users/320027671/Desktop/JmeterPerformanceSuit/CompleteSuit/STU3/Post/index.csv");
file.each { line ->
 index << line
 randoms << __Random(0,size,)
}
```

The script is giving error

> the method does not exists

the scirpt is working uptil index << line, the problem is with random function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you use groovy as language (otherwise it won't work)

You can't use [JMeter functions inside JSR223](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47305382/jmeter-submit-jmeter-function-inside-a-script-jsr223-element)

You can randomize every line using for example [RandomUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomUtils.html#nextInt-int-int-):

```
org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextInt(0, size-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach may fail to produce "random" numbers, especially on lesser file sizes you can get **duplicate** values in the `randoms` list so I would recommend doing something like:

```
1.upto(size, { i ->
    randoms.add(i)
})

Collections.shuffle(randoms)
```

This will populate `randoms` list with the numbers from 1 to the length of `size` and then calls [Collection.shuffle()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-) function in order to "randomise" the list.

Just in case check out [Writing JMeter Functions in Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/writing-jmeter-functions-in-groovy) for more insights.