# I am unable to get the output of a Jmeter hash function

Tags: hash, scripting, sha1, beanshell, jmeter-5.0

I am doing double hashing of few parameters and the 2nd hashed value I want to use in my jmeter script as a parameter.But my output is not getting into the parameter value.Please help

I have written the hash function of the variables in a Beanshell Sampler and I am getting the output.But that is not getting into the request parameter

```
import java.util.*;
import java.security.MessageDigest;

String UserID16= vars.get("UID16");
String passwordToHash16 = 'test123' ;
String IBSKey16 = 'IBSKey' ;
String RanNum16 = vars.get("RandomNum16");

String hash1st = ${__digest(SHA-1,${UID16}test123IBSKey)} ;

String hash2nd = ${__digest(SHA-1,${Hash1st}${RandomNum16})} ;

vars.put("hashPassword16", hash2nd);
```

${hashPassword16} variable I am passing in the request parameter value. That should give me the 2nd Hashed value. But that is just passed as hashPassword16.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47305382/jmeter-submit-jmeter-function-inside-a-script-jsr223-element

Comment: @user7294900 This is not working. I want the output as a parameter which I can use in the requests further.